# Python virtualenv setuptools package issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, mxnet

Using virtualenv with -p python2
While installing `pip install gluoncv` it errors out with following error

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./mxv16_p2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (45.0.0)
ERROR: Package 'setuptools' requires a different Python: 2.7.12 not in '>=3.5'
```

Comment: Are you downloading the distributions from _PyPI_ directly?

Comment: yes. From pyPi directly.

Comment: OK, then I don't understand, I can't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1493

Specifically this comment : https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1493#issuecomment-576250710

```
pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<45.0.0'
```

It expected a lower version of setuptools and hence pip install --upgrade to lower version [i.e. downgraded]

Comment: If I understood correctly it should not be necessary if the distributions are downloaded directly from _PyPI_ or any other fully compatible index. It could be necessary if you are downloading from an index that is not full-featured.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to do that. Any idea why my "index was not full-featured"?

Comment: If you are using _PyPI_ then it should not be necessary, unless I misunderstood something. See for example [this comment](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1493#issuecomment-578226398). I don't know what your exact setup is. There are some more details in the _GitHub_ discussion.